# customize array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array 
             ([category_name] => Operating System
              [sub_category_name] => Windows 8) 
         [1] => Array 
             ([category_name] => Operating System
              [sub_category_name] => Linux)
         [2] => Array 
             ([category_name] => Mobile
              [sub_category_name] => Nokia))
```

I would like to customize it like this:

```
Array('Operating System' => 'Windows 8', 'Operating System' => 'Linux', 'Mobile' => 'Nokia')
```

Thanks in advance. Any help or suggestion would be a great help...

Comment: 2 foreach -> Print all values in 1 new array

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger how i can write 2 foreach...could you please give me more details.. so that i can try..

Comment: @Muhammad :| Please have a look [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413589/php-foreach-with-multidimensional-array) This is basic and can easily be found with a little search.

Comment: The sample ARRAY you posted cannot be achieve because you have Operating System as KEY twice and this will overwrite values. If you want to just echo than you can surely do a Foreach or while, but if you want the ARRAY as variable than it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help

```
$result = array();
foreach($firstArray as $row) {
    $result[$row['category_name']] = $row['sub_category_name'];
}
```

if you want to merge duplicate keys you can write like this

```
$result = array();
foreach($firstArray as $row) {
    if(isset($result[$row['category_name']])) {
        if(!is_array($result[$row['category_name']])) {
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp[] = $result[$row['category_name']];
            $result[$row['category_name']] = $tmp;
        }
        $result[$row['category_name']][] = $row['sub_category_name'];
    } else 
    $result[$row['category_name']] = $row['sub_category_name'];
}
```

Comment: Sir thanks,,, but your code giving me..
    Array
    (
       [0] => Operating System
       [1] => Windows 8
       [2] => Operating System

    )
and my requirement is different..

Comment: you want remove duplicate elements? @Muhammad

Comment: no.. i want the category and sub_category should come as key and values

Comment: check out my answer, it should do what you are looking for

Comment: i am really very sorry :( .. i have updated the required output in the question...

Comment: @Muhammad like this? `Array ( Operating System  => Windows 8 ...)` ?

Comment: @Farnabaz thank you very much sir..this is also fits in my requirement.. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$n = array();
$i = 0;

array_walk($arr, function($subArr) {
    global $n;
    global $i;
    $n[$subArr['category_name'] . $i] = $subArr['sub_category_name'];
    $i++;
});

var_dump($n); // array(3) { ["Operating System0"]=> string(9) "Windows 8" ["Operating System1"]=> string(5) "Linux" ["Mobile2"]=> string(5) "Nokia" }
```

**NOTE:** As OP updated question, I updated answer too, though in the same array the same keys are not permitted, so I added counter at the end of the key in the new array.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/7RXbUq)</kbd>

Comment: i am really very sorry :( .. i have updated the required output in the question...

Comment: you can't have duplicates key in array

Comment: what he want is different, look output in question

Comment: @crypticous sir thank you very much.. for your important time.. but you demo `$arr` is deffirent from my question array...

Comment: @Muhammad Because of numbers at the end of the keys yes ? Sure it is because in the array same keys aren't permitted, in this case your information will be omitted !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50121/discussion-between-crypticous-and-muhammad)

Comment: @ToKeN Sir .. thank you very much sir.. for your important time.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
PHP does not allow duplicate keys for same array.
If you want to use same keys for multiple values then you should use multidimensional array as mentioned in below example.

As per your above code below is your array 
$array = array("0" => array("category_name" => "Operating System", "sub_category_name" => "Windows 8"),
    "1" => array("category_name" => "Operating System", "sub_category_name" => "Linux"),
    "2" => array("category_name" => "Mobile", "sub_category_name" => "Nokia"));

you can merge the array and for same key use multidimensional array

$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) {

    $arrmerge = array($arr['category_name'] => $arr['sub_category_name']);
    if (array_key_exists($arr['category_name'], $new_array)) {
        $arrmerge[$arr['category_name']] = array($new_array[$arr['category_name']], $arr['sub_category_name']);
    }

    $new_array = array_merge($new_array, $arrmerge);
}
print_r($new_array);

I hope this will help you.
```