# Loops into a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array in PHP:

```
 [data] => Array
        (
            [BOO_item_quantity] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 6
                )

            [BOO_item_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 18
                    [1] => 13
                )

            [BOO_item_price] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 0
                )

        )
```

How is it possible to loop into this to get something like this please ?

```
Quantity = 1 - Item_Id = 18 - Price = 3
Quantity = 6 - Item_Id = 13 - Price = 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes my dude of course it is you just gotta do it.

Comment: yes it is possible, just use a `foreach`

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413589/php-foreach-with-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Do you have control over the array format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [*foreach*](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) statement to loop over the elements the first sub-array:

```
$data = array(
    'BOO_item_quantity' => array(1,6),
    'BOO_item_id' => array(18,13),
    'BOO_item_price' =>array(3,0)
);
foreach($data['BOO_item_quantity'] as $index=>$value) {
    print 'Quantity = '.$value.' - Item_Id = '.$data['BOO_item_id'][$index].' - Price = '.$data['BOO_item_price'][$index].'<br />';
}
```

See it in action at [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/viu2-a8b1).