# Foreach comes back as Array Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with this one, but when I attempt to do a `foreach` loop with a variable, it comes back with `Array Array`.

**PHP Code:**

```
  <?php foreach ($thing as $t) : ?>
    <?php $thisStuff = $t[stuff];  ?>
    <?php echo $thisStuff; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Output:**
`Array Array`

Could this be possibly that there is another array within `$thisStuff`? If so would I loop through that data?

Comment: _Could this be possibly that there is another array within $thisStuff?_ Yes.  `print_r($thing);`

Comment: I did and it comes back with a bunch of other arrays. So, how would I structure that data? That's what I'm confused about since I've never really worked with nested arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php foreach with multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413589/php-foreach-with-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Maybe update question with the print_r result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multidimensional array you'll need to use a recursive function.

an example might be this

```
function unfoldArray($array,$output = array()) {
    if(is_object($array)) {
        $array = (array)$array;
    }
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            //$output[] = $key;
            $output = unfoldArray($value,$output);
        } else {
            $output[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

the above function, given an array like

```
$array = array(
    "one",
    "two",
    "three" => array("A","B","C"),
    "four" => array("X","Y","Z"),
    "five",
    "six" => array(
        "sub_one",
        "sub_two",
        "sub_three" => array("sub_A","sub_B","sub_C")
    ),
    "seven"
);
$output = unfoldArray($array);
```

would return a flat array like this

```
   // $output 
   [
        "one",
        "two",
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "X",
        "Y",
        "Z",
        "five",
        "sub_one",
        "sub_two",
        "sub_A",
        "sub_B",
        "sub_C",
        "seven"
    ]
```

you may notice that values "three" and "six" are omitted from the result array because they are key, but if you wan to include them just uncomment the line //$output[] = $key; in the function.

Once you have this array you may just loop with a foreach.
This might not be exactly what you need, but should give you a direction to follow.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Yeah, I was messing around with nesting a `foreach` loop in another `foreach` loop and while I'm getting the results it just seems really messy.

Answer (score 0):

Try with key => value method:

```
  <?php foreach ($thing as $key => $value) : ?>
    // if $value is array, you need to iterate it the same way (additional foreach)
    <?php echo $value; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Works for an Associative array. Not a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: If it's multidimensional array, you need to use another foreach inside this one

Comment: to me, it sounds like he has an array of associative arrays...but yes @mitch i agree.

Comment: Yeah, there are a bunch of nested arrays within other arrays. Sheesh, this is going to be messy.