# PHP: CSV to Array and Array to HTML

Tags: php, html, csv

I have converted an **one-column** CSV into a PHP associative array with the following code:

```
$file = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv'));
```

And now I have something like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Value 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => Value 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => Value 3 )
.
.
.
[i] => Array ( [0] => Value i )
)
```

How can I put those values into a HTML form? I have tried it using `foreach ($file as $pos => $pos2 => $pos3)` to declare the loop, but the form still shows "Array" as output.

Also, is there any way to get a simple numeric array from this CSV?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413589/php-foreach-with-multidimensional-array

Comment: Many thanks. It's basically the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have array of arrays and you need values under key `0` in each subarray, your code can be:

```
foreach ($file as $pos) {
    echo $pos[0];
}
```

Comment: I think the op is missing understanding in how array and foreach works. This solution seems clear to me but i'm not sure he will get it.

Comment: If I fully understand `foreach` and arrays in PHP I wouldn't be here asking this question, but of course I get the solution provided by @u_mulder . I'm not that stupid, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much @u_mulder . It works like a charm.