# How to use foreach loop in PHP to execute multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am pulling data from a multidimensional array. While using foreach loop, I am getting confused and can't pull out data from my array. Here is my array named as $result_array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 19
                    [category_name] => Food
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 16
                    [category_name] => Gourmet
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 17
                    [category_name] => Islamic Product
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )


        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 28
                    [category_name] => Dry Food
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 39
                    [category_name] => Testt
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 37
                    [category_name] => Seasonal Items
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 38
                    [category_name] => Icon Items
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 29
                    [category_name] => Biscuits
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 30
                    [category_name] => Nutty
                    [publication_status] => 1
                    [deletion_status] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Here is my loop:

```
foreach($result_array as $info) {
    echo $info['category_name'].'<br>';
}
```

This loop is giving me an error saying undefined index `category_name`. I am newbie in this field. Can anyone enlighten me up? Thanks

Comment: Nope @Siraj . My array is different than that. Answer is already given. I had to use foreach 2 times

Comment: Then read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29363646/5132337

Comment: Missed that. Got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need double foreach, like this:

```
foreach($result_array as $outer_array)
    foreach($outer_array as $inner_array)
        echo $inner_array['category_name'] . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$result_array` you are looping over has 4 elements and none of them have value with key `category_name`. You need to do double `foreach` or something wiser there.