# How to all get key values of nested array with foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDZma.png)

my code is like the following:

```
foreach ($tmpArray as $keys => $values) {
        if(is_array($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
                if($key == "category_name"){
                    echo $value['category_name'];
                }
            }
        } else {
            if($keys == "category_name"){
                echo $values;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output: Vasıta->Bmw X Serisi
I want to do : Vasıta->Bmw X Serisi->Deneme

How do I print the category_name with `foreach` loop?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Some kind of recursive walk through nested arrays should do the job.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413809/6552776) could be the answer you're looking for!

Comment: Thank you very much bro(@csabinho) . Problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (is_array($tmpArray)) {
echo isset($tmpArray['category_name']) ? $tmpArray['category_name'] . '->' : '';
foreach ($tmpArray as $key1 => $value1) {
    if (is_array($value1)) {
        echo isset($value1['category_name']) ? $value1['category_name'] . '->' : '';
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if (is_array($value2)) {
                echo isset($value2['category_name']) ? $value2['category_name'] : '';
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I want to output : Vasıta->Bmw X Serisi->Deneme. Your output:Vasıta->Bmw X Serisi . But there is no need. array_walk_recursive($tmpArray, function ($item, $key) {}}); my work resolved. thank you for your help.