# PHP - mysqli_query in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

First sorry if you think the question is stupid but im new in php.., so the question is: Is it okay to use foreach loop instead of while loop?

Here is an example of what I have in mind:

```
foreach(mysqli_query($db_connect, 'SELECT * FROM exampletable') as $row)
{
    echo $row['exampleitem'];
}
```

It's working, but I'm not sure is it right, secure, slow and etc..

Comment: seems like a better use of foreach, they are basically the same.  So if you find it easier to use one or the other for different examples you shouldnt worry.

Comment: Thank you, for me is better, cuz it allows you to use query direct in "foreach"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is OK. `mysqli_query` returns a `mysqli_result` object. The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) says:

> 5.4.0 `Iterator` support was added, as `mysqli_result` now implements `Traversable`.