# How can I foreach loop this array in php

Tags: php

How can I foreach loop this array:
`Array ( [0] => Array ( [stage_level_idstage_level] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [stage_level_idstage_level] => 2 ) )`

I've tried some things but it wont work..

Comment: what is your intended result? & what have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php foreach with multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413589/php-foreach-with-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

foreach($arrayName as $arr)
{
  foreach($arr as $item){
          .......
  }
}

?>
```